# syntax error near unexpected token `|' '/Start-Batch.sh: line 1:

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

While executing SH Script it showing error  syntax error near unexpected token `|' '/Start-Batch.sh: line 1:

```
|
a='ps -ef|grep SpringBoot.jar|grep -v grep|awk {'print $2'}'
 echo "PID:"$a
   if["${a:-0}" ==0 ];then
     
        nohup /opt/../java -Xms1g -Xmx3g -jar SpringBoot.jar & disown
        
    else
    
    echo "Already Job is running, Please stop the orginal process"
fi
```

Comment: The first line with `|` is not valid shell syntax. Get rid of that.

Comment: You also need spaces around `[` and `==` in the `if` statement. Paste your code into shellcheck.net.